# How to get a DataTrigger in a UserControl?

Tags: wpf, user-controls, datatrigger

In a UserControl I have a Storyboard for an animation that must use *Storyboard.TargetName*.

I want to start/stop the animnation via a DataTrigger.
A DataTrigger can be added to a Style.
But: A Storyboard tree in a Style cannot specify a TargetName.

And: Triggers collection members must be of type EventTrigger.
Therefore I cannot add the DataTrigger to *UserControl.Triggers*.

What should I do (in terms of solving the problem)?

Comment: I have an idea how to fix it, but can you please show the relevant XAML? Please at least include the `Storyboard`, the `DataTrigger` and the two UI elements involved.

Comment: Ok, don't worry, I don't think that I need it now... hopefully you can make sense of my answer without it.

Answer (score 1):

It would have been easier to explain this if you had shown the relevant code, but I'll have a go anyway. The answer is simpler than you think... just move the `Storyboard` to the element that you would have specified as the `Storyboard` target.

For example, if you were trying to add a `Storyboard` to a `ToggleButton` to change the `Opacity` of a `TextBlock` when the user clicks, or checks the `Button`, then you can just move the `Storyboard` to the `TextBlock.Style.Triggers` collection and set the `DataTrigger` to trigger when the `ToggleButton.IsChecked` value is `True`.

The basic idea is this:

> Instead of using a `DataTrigger` in control A to change something from control B when something happens in control A, reverse the situation. Use the `DataTrigger` in control B to change something in control B when something happens in control A.